# Setting IIS to redirect all requests to another server

Tags: iis, redirect, redirection

My company currently added a new IIS server called server2 to replace server1.
I would like all traffic that tries to access server1 to be redirected to server2.
Is there a quick way to do this in IIS.

For instance, if a user enters

http://server1 they get http://server2 after the redirect.

Furthermore, if a user enters

http://server1/king.aspx?quest=1 they get http://server2/king.aspx?quest=1 after the redirect.

Comment: Which version of IIS?

Comment: The version of IIS is IIS6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, ISAPI_Rewrite can do exactly what you need.  There is a free version.

http://www.isapirewrite.com/